# MAO: internal microphone is too loud (saturates)

Tags: microphone, jack

When I record something from my internal mic from Jack, the microphone is way too loud, which makes it saturate:

[image]

As I want to use SooperLooper, I tried to change directly the input gain from the software via "input gain": the sound is lower, but the sound is still distorded due to saturation (it is just quiter). I guess the gain is changed after the clipping occurs, so it is too late in the process of acquisition... I also tried to put Carla + an audio Gain filter... same issue.

How could I change my internal microphone input gain to avoid the clipping and distorded saturated sound?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use alsamixer. In fact, what happens is that jack sits on top of alsa, so alsa must be used to configure the microphone volume. Fun fact: I need to put the volume to zero !